# Verification (Update DB if email and token is correct)

Tags: php, html, css, database

Verification (Update DB if email and token is correct)

But even if my code is invalid ,it still show **"Great Success"** , but in my DB the status won't update

But if i insert correct code , it show **"Great Success"** , but my DB will update the status

Comment: Try this, $query = "update users set status='1' where username = ". " '$username' and code='$code' ";

Answer (score 0):

in this code you are checking the executing of the command, which runs in each state.
you need to read again status from the table If the status had changed. you show "Great success!" otherwise show "Failed". This is the easiest way.
Of course, there are other ways.

Comment: Hello, After $query code , in below i need to create a query again to read the status from 0/1  ?

Comment: yes, you need to create query again for reading status. Of course, you can check status without creating the query but this the hard way. please use print_r for $query Inside condition (if($db->query($query))) and put the values here

Answer (score 0):

your code runs always true that is why it always says "Great success!" I think. and maybe you need to check it first if the user and code exist in db then do the condition update else fail.

Answer (score 0):

first you can add the `select` query and check for code and username is correct or not and after adding `update` query.

Thanks for the help - The codes works